# ¿Como procesar una funcion php con ajax, validar si se cumple o no?

Tags: php, ajax

Buenas estoy trabajando con una pequeña funcion en php el cual me permite consultas datos a una tabla mysql entonces uso esta funcion php

```
public function showUsers($idAccounts)
    {

        $search = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT usuarios from usuarios where cuentas_id = :id");
        $search->bindParam(':id', $idAccounts, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $search->execute();
        if ($search->rowCount() >= 1) {
           return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
       
    }
```

Si hay registros y ejecuta mando a retornar un true caso contrario un false
Ahora con ajax quisiera mostrar un alert que me diga si hay o no registros para ello tengo esto

```
  $("#form").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const idAccounts = $("#idAccounts").val();
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "usuarios.php",
    data: {
      idAccounts: idAccounts
    },
    success: function (result) {
     console.log(result)
     if(result==true){
        alert('si')
     }else{
        alert('no');
     }
    },
  });
});
```

Pero siempre me muestra que no hay registros. No se donde estoy mal.

Comment: acabo de volver a pegarlo

Comment: Si ya lo eh corregido

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar exactamente qué te muestra?

Comment: en consola no muestra nada, y solo me salta el alert('no') a pesar que si se esta ejecutando la funcion y la consulta correctamente

Comment: Muestra cómo recibes los datos del POST y llamas a `showUsers()` en PHP. Dinos qué te muestra el `console.log` en consola.

Comment: eso digo en consola no muestra nada ni errores ni nada `$recibir->showUsers($idAccounts)` asi recibo los datos enviados por post

Comment: Hola Fer, nos puedes compartir un poco más de tu usuarios.php para ver cómo estás recibiendo la informacion

Comment: si en usuarios.php lo recibo de la siguiente manera 
`<?php

$obj = new users();

if (isset($_POST['idAccounts'])) {
    $idAccounts = $_POST['idAccounts'];
       $obj->searchUsers($idAccounts);
}`